# Can we save base64 image to smartstore in salesforce sdk in Hybrid App?

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, base64

We want to save bae64 image into smartstore in salesforcesdk in android mobile using phonegap (Hybrid App)?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Like it is described in the [Cordova Camera Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) you're of course able to save the pictures in Base64:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#navigatorcameragetpicture